# Regex for capturing all the urls in a paragraph except for a specific domain

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I need to capture all the urls in a paragraph apart from the urls from a specific domain/ sub domain.For example in the below paragraph I need to capture all the urls apart from example.com

"This is a paragraph name.url.com it contains random urls name-dev.url.com name-qa.url.com [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) test.example.com http://TestCaSeSensetivEUrl.com  http://www.test.com https://www.example.com test.com"

**Urls I need to capture**

- name.url.com
- name-dev.url.com
- name-qa.url.com
- http://TestCaSeSensetivEUrl.com
- http://www.test.com
- test.com

**Urls I don't need to capture as below**

- [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)
- test.example.com
- https://www.example.com

I have tried the below regex using negative look behind method, but it's not working as I need.

`/(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?([a-z0-9]+(?<!example)[\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9+]+(?<!example)\.[a-z]{2,5})/gi`

Comment: See [this idea](https://regex101.com/r/vpHDiG/1)... don't know if it's good at all to mach urls like that.

Comment: It is php or javascript?

Comment: If you get tired of tinkering with a single regex, just catch all URLs, and then filter the unwanted items with e.g. `preg_grep('~example\.com~', $matches', PREG_GREP_INVERT)` (see [preg_grep](https://php.net/preg_grep)), or with `array_filter($matches ,fn($x) => !str_contains($x, 'example.com')`.

Comment: Hi @bobblebubble , Thanks for your answer. It is working for the most of the part. I also need to match this type of urls as well. https://www.test1.com/sdkfjndgkjg. Can you please help on this?

Comment: Hi @Thefourthbird, It is for both javascript and php actually.

Comment: @aklucian It's impossible to help without knowing every case. Most simple for your additional case would be to attach something like [`(?:[?\/]\S*)?`](https://regex101.com/r/5Qlkzg/1). These patterns from me do not work if you have urls in quotes or urls that do start/end with other than white-space.

Comment: Hi @bobblebubble, Can you please mention exactly where to attach in [this](https://regex101.com/r/vpHDiG/1).

Comment: You mean [this](https://regex101.com/r/5Qlkzg/1)? (link on pattern from my last comment). Better you make a new question as soon as you know all the possible cases.

Comment: Hi @bobblebubble, Thanks for the update. I will make a new question as you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be sufficient for your use case:

```
/(?<!\S)(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:(?:(?!example)\w+[.-])+[a-z]{2,11})(?!\S)/gi
```

See https://regex101.com/r/NdOxKt/1 for a demonstration of the regex at work. Below is a rough explanation of what the regex is doing:

- The leading and trailing `(?<!\S)` essentially splits the string into segments on space characters, including whitespace and newlines
- The `?:` syntax makes each set of parenthesis it is in a non-capture group, saving memory on the machine where it is ran and speeding up your execution time
- `(?:https?:\/\/)?` optionally matches both `http` and `https` for URLs without matching the invalid characters `:` and `/` anywhere else in the URL
- `(?:(?!example)\w+[.-])+` looks for one or more words that do not match `example`, followed by either a hyphen or a period
- `[a-z]{2,11}` matches the final domain extension, i.e. `com`, `org`, or `enterprises`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. I have tried this regex code but it is not capturing all the urls I need to. This is the link that I have tried [link](https://regex101.com/r/nU4URU/1) Is something missing this?

Comment: @aklucian you're absolutely right, I wrote the regex to match the URLs you mentioned without remembering the context of the paragraph that you mentioned. I'm out of town for the weekend but I'll try to get back to you on Monday to fix your issue!

Comment: Hi @Aaron Meese, Ok sure. Thanks

Comment: @aklucian check out the new update, this should solve your problem :)

Comment: @aklucian have you checked out the updated answer? It seems to work perfectly for what you were asking

Comment: Hi Aaron Meese, Thanks for the updated. I needed to capture this type of urls as well. https://test.com/test. @bobble bubble provided the patern to match this in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

this could be a solution

```
^(https?:\/\/)?(?!(?:www\.)?google\.*)([\da-zA-Z.-]+)\.([a-zA-Z\.]{2,6})([\/\w .-]*)*\/?$
```

for example here google is excluded from being captured

Comment: Hi MarcoWriteCode, Looks like there's an error in this regex. It is not working.